# How to determine the value of a restraint of trade?

Tags: employment

I'm considering a sole trader employment contract that has a 6 month restraint of trade after termination clause against soliciting "any business from any client or actively sought prospective clients of [the company]" and non-solicitation of associated people clause. It also says that the (to be) agreed fee covers compensation for this.

Assuming that this is negotiable, what would a fair and reasonable amount of compensation for this restraint be?

I've searched and the only resources I've managed to find are [a proposed law](https://russelldrakeconsulting.co.nz/2023/03/17/is-there-any-value-in-restraint-of-trade-clauses/)  that suggests 50% of salary for 6 months and [a helpful article](https://web.archive.org/web/20230323024119/https://www.lawsociety.org.nz/news/publications/lawtalk/issue-886/the-value-of-restraint/) about restraint of trade when selling a business. I have heard of employees that have a "full salary while restrained" agreement.

Comment: Question to the Mods - why has this been Migrated here? The question is definitely a Legal one - since its asking what is the Compensation (something determined either by Settlement or by a Judge) for a legal clause - the fact it's about a restraint of trade clause doesn't make it applicable here.

Comment: @TheDemonLord As I understand the question, it is about compensation. Something determined by both parties agreeing, with laws maybe limiting what they can legally agree to (for example minimum wage laws). This seems very common and should be something well educated HR departments should know, so it is perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The question is about what a fair amount of compensation would be. It's not a 'take it or leave it' situation. I will update the question.

Comment: So I can avoid asking bad questions in the future. What is wrong with this question that has caused so many downvotes?

Comment: @glennr - Ah, the Clarification makes a lot more sense - the way it was written, it sounded like you were asking for *after the fact* as opposed to *what is normally accepted to put in* - I still think Legal SE could (and should) have answered it - as what is common in a contract would normally be under their purview - but whatevs. We are nicer than lawyers.

Answer (score 3):

> How would the amount of compensation be determined?

By you determining what is it worth to not be able to, effectively, chase any work in even remotely related field to the client for bloody 6 months after you've stopped working with them.

Why do I say "even remotely related"? Because unless you want to deal with potential lawsuit, that's what you will have to do, otherwise you put yourself at risk of receiving a letter from their lawyer. Whether they are right or not, it's a hassle you will now have to deal with it.

In my case whenever someone asks me to sign someone like this, they hear a price back that is not something they will ever pay, as it's an absolutely horrible thing to sign unless you get a very major upside (aka payout way higher than you would earn from working), or are desperate for any work and the 6 months after will have to be future's you problem.